# Infinite "for i,v in pairs(table) do" Loop?

Tags: loops, lua, infinite-loop, roblox

```
if #subWords>0 then 
print("Q3") 
for a,b in pairs(subWords) do 
table.insert(output,b) 
print("Q2: Adding "..b) 
end 
end
```

**----Definitions**

--subWords is a table with four strings in it

--output is a table, with strings in it

**----Goal**

--To merge the tables "output" and "subWords"

**----Output**

--Repeatedly prints "Q2: Adding (word)" (after other stuff)

--Crashes ROBLOX

Any ideas?

Comment: `output` and `subWords` are definitely different tables, right?

Comment: Yes. And I also fixed the crashing problem, but it is still an infinite loop :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Phrogz comment: subWords and output are the same table.

Note that in Lua, tables values are *references*, so:

```
t1 = {}
t2 = t1
t3 = t2
t4 = t3

// all four of these variables refer to the *same* table

print(t4.food) -- nil
t1.food = "donut"
print(t4.food) -- donut
```

What's happening with your code is that `subWords` and `output` are referencing the same table. As you loop through the items in this table you're *adding* new items to it, so the loop will never be done.

I know you said this is not the case, but that's the only thing that could produce those symptoms. Try `output = {}` before the loop and you'll see the problem goes away. Or you could `assert(output ~= subWords)` or `print(output, subWords)` to see that they're the same, but I don't know how Roblox handles those functions (it may not have an output console and/or it may trap errors).

Comment: Thanks for the help. print(output, subWords) was a great suggestion, as I would never have believed that the tables were the same :) I forgot the output table was not local and I rewrote it in the line before... Thanks again!

Comment: Was slamming my head against my desk with a similar problem. Thank you! In this case it was updating some internal structures for use with an IUP application.

Answer (score 1):

Smells like subWords and Output is the same table.
And when traversing tables, never add values to tables being traversed, as stated in the Lua Reference Manual:

> [snip]
>
> The behavior of next is undefined if,
> during the traversal, you assign any
> value to a non-existent field in the
> table. You may however modify existing
> fields. In particular, you may clear
> existing fields.
>
> [snip]

And `pairs()`uses next internally.